# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException Error JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am getting a error that I do not fully understand, why is it showing up ?
I have a form where I enter details into relevant JTextBoxes and data from those textboxes should be sent to a database I have set up on my local.

Full error message

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException. You have an error in your 
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right   syntax to use near ')VALUES'asd','asd',",",",",",",'Home','Female','White  
British' at line 1
```

Code

```
conn = (Connection) SQLConnect.ConnectDb();
    //inserting all values to database
    String sql = "INSERT INTO w1283057.criminalrecords "
            + "(FName, MName, Sname, DOB, Address, HPhone, BPhone, MPhone "
            + "ResidentStatus, Sex, Race, IncidentLocation, Zone, PremiseType "
            + "DateRecorded, TimeRecorded, Weapons, CrimeOffences) "
            + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    try{
        //Declaring all variable that wiil be collected from JTextField
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        //coverting JText to String
        String fname = FName.getText();
        String mname = MName.getText();
        String surname = Surname.getText();
        String dob = DOB.getText();
        String fullAddress = FullAddress.getText();
        String hPhone = HPhone.getText();
        String bPhone = BPhone.getText();
        String mPhone = MPhone.getText();
        String incidentLocation = IncidentLocation.getText();
        String incidentZone = IncidentZone.getText();
        String incidentPrType = IncidentPrType.getText();
        String incidentDate = IncidentDate.getText();
        String incidentTime = IncidentTime.getText();
        String incidentWeapons = IncidentWeapons.getText();
        String crimeOffences = CrimeOffences.getText();
        String radioText = "";

        //collecting input data and assign them to variables            
            pst.setString(1, fname);
            pst.setString(2, mname);
            pst.setString(3, surname);
            pst.setString(4, dob);
            pst.setString(5, fullAddress);
            pst.setString(6, hPhone);
            pst.setString(7, bPhone);
            pst.setString(8, mPhone);
            //radio buttons Resident Status
            if(RHome.isSelected())
            {
                radioText = RHome.getText();
                pst.setString(9, radioText);
            }
            else if(RForeign.isSelected())
            {
                radioText = RForeign.getText();
                pst.setString(9, radioText);
            }
            //radio buttons Sex
            if(Male.isSelected())
            {
                radioText = Male.getText();
                pst.setString(10, radioText);

            }
            else if(Female.isSelected())
            {
                radioText = Female.getText();
                pst.setString(10, radioText);
            }
            //radio button Race
            if(WhiteBritish.isSelected())
            {
                radioText = WhiteBritish.getText();
                pst.setString(11, radioText);

            }
            else if(WhiteOther.isSelected())
            {
                radioText = WhiteOther.getText();
                pst.setString(11, radioText);
            }
            else if(Black.isSelected())
            {
                radioText = Black.getText();
                pst.setString(11, radioText);
            }
            else if(Asian.isSelected())
            {
                radioText = Asian.getText();
                pst.setString(11, radioText);
            }
            else if(Indian.isSelected())
            {
                radioText = Indian.getText();
                pst.setString(11, radioText);
            }
            /////////////////////////////////////
            pst.setString(12, incidentLocation);
            pst.setString(13, incidentZone);
            pst.setString(14, incidentPrType);
            pst.setString(15, incidentDate);
            pst.setString(16, incidentTime);
            pst.setString(17, incidentWeapons);
            pst.setString(18, crimeOffences);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("records added sucessfully");

    }
    catch (SQLException a)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, a);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I will also suggest not use single quotes in your sql.

Comment: The prepared statement will take care of the quotation requirement

Comment: @BryanMoyles I know Its does not make much difference, but it provides easy reading.

Comment: The error message shows a missing opening bracket (after `values`) , yet your code includes it. Is it possible you are not showing us the code you actually run?

Comment: I have copied exactly the code i have in my compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO w1283057.criminalrecords "
        + "(FName, MName, Sname, DOB, Address, HPhone, BPhone, MPhone "
        + "ResidentStatus, Sex, Race, IncidentLocation, Zone, PremiseType "
        + "DateRecorded, TimeRecorded, Weapons, CrimeOffences) "
        + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Try this... After the fields (MPhone, PremiseType) lack the comma

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO w1283057.criminalrecords "
        + "(FName, MName, Sname, DOB, Address, HPhone, BPhone, MPhone, "
        + "ResidentStatus, Sex, Race, IncidentLocation, Zone, PremiseType, "
        + "DateRecorded, TimeRecorded, Weapons, CrimeOffences) "
        + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Greetings.

Comment: We have already figured out the right answer :) i was just waiting for someone to submit it, for everyone reference :) so thank you

Answer (score 5):

You have a comma at the end of your value list, get rid of it, or populate it with an appropriate value.

```
+ "DateRecorded, TimeRecorded, Weapons, CrimeOffences,) " <---
+ "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,)"; <----
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, i have done as you said but i still get this error

Comment: @MaciejCygan Check you have same column name listed as those of `?` in prepared statement. I mean you should have 18 column names and `?` as stated in your code.

Comment: Can you please update your code to show what you currently have? I'll have to agree with @smit and make the assumption that your column count isn't matching, or that you haven't removed the ending comma from both of the lines I have in my answer

Comment: Yes i have 18 columns, and 18 question marks?, i have checked in my DB and there are also 18 column, i even checked the names if they are correct in DB and Code and they match. I have a feeling like this error could be caused by those radiobuttons but not entirely sure

Comment: Yes thats what I pointing now that can you share your DB schema. They have to `varchar` to set string for those values.

Comment: This is kinda nice typo mistake . You are missing `,` at the end of `sql` at `MPhone` and `PremiseType `. Just add those `,` after these two words and I think you are good to go.

Comment: @MaciejCygan there's something definitely not right with the error, if you're receiving the same exact error. Why are the parenthesis disappearing when the query is actually being executed? If you can enable mysql logging I'd like to see what mysql is trying to execute

Comment: i am using virtual db, on localhost. I do not currently have external db

Comment: @MaciejCygan Better take a look at my previous comment. I pointed a mistake which could cause problem.

Comment: Ok got it yes smit thank you, i havent noticed this. :) problem solved all now works :) thank you everyone for contribution

Comment: @BryanMoyles Better you should update your answer. This is not getting matche with reference to the question modified now.

Comment: smit you prefer you can submit a "answer question" i will mark on yours as solution :)

Comment: @BryanMoyles I edited one line to your answer to match modified context of question. I hope you don't mind.